# React Draft Wysiwyg: Image Upload when I click the "Add" Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

On a React.js Application I try to make the https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs editor to upload an image and embend it into the editor's content.

So Far I managed to do this with this piece of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import {convertFromRaw, convertToRaw, EditorState} from 'draft-js';    
import "../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css"
import "../../node_modules/draft-js-image-plugin/lib/plugin.css"



export default class CustomEditor extends Component {

  uploadCallback(file) {

    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        var reader=new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
          Meteor.call('fileStorage.uploadFile',reader.result,file.name,file.type,(err,response)=>{
              console.log(response)
             if(err){
               reject(err)
             }

             resolve({ data: { link: response.data.url } });
          })
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {

    const config={
      image: { uploadCallback: this.uploadCallback }
    }

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Editor toolbar={ config } />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But my problem is that the image uploading procces gets initiated when I select the file, what I want to initiate the upload process when I click on "Add" button as you see in the image bellow:

[image: Button to add the Image]

So how I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to change this behavior.

The only option you can provide is `uploadCallback`, see the [docs](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs).

You can find the source for the upload code [here](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/blob/master/src/controls/Image/Component/index.js#L132-L150), it's quite clear, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

use toolbar props inside editor toolbar={image: { uploadCallback: uploadCallback }} and write a uploadCallback function like this below.

```js
const uploadCallback = (file, callback) => {
    console.log(file);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new window.FileReader();
      console.log(reader);
      reader.onloadend = async () => {
        const form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("file", file);
        const res = await uploadFile(form_data);
        setValue("thumbnail", res.data);
        resolve({ data: { link: process.env.REACT_APP_API + res.data } });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };

  const config = {
    image: { uploadCallback: uploadCallback },
  };
```

```html
<Editor
  toolbar={config}
  editorState={editorState}
  toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
  wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
  editorClassName="editorClassName"
  onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
  placeholder="Write your comment here"
/>
```